# Escape (Grave) Character in Powershell

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell, backticks

The recommended installation instructions for [AWS Copilot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/AWS_Copilot.html) on Windows are:

```
New-Item -Path 'C:\copilot' -ItemType directory; `
  Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile 'C:\copilot\copilot.exe' https://github.com/aws/copilot-cli/releases/latest/download/copilot-windows.exe
```

According to the [Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-5.1), the escape character has a ton of usages, but I don't understand how it is being used in the statement given to us by Amazon to install Copilot.

Could someone clarify the usage of ` in the first line?

[the code works fine, just wondering about usage]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backtick `` ` `` can be used as a [line continuation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-5.1#line-continuation), for instance, when dealing with multiple parameters.

A simple example of valid syntax:

```bash
Get-ChildItem `
    -Path . `
    -Filter *.ps1 `
    -File
```

However, this usage can 100% of the times be replaced for a *better / cleaner* form of parameter binding, called [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.3):

```bash
$getChildItemSplat = @{
    Path   = '.'
    Filter = '*.ps1'
    File   = $true
}
Get-ChildItem @getChildItemSplat
```

For the specifics of your question, the `` ` `` is completely unnecessary and the same can be said for the `;`.

The following would work as well:

```bash
New-Item -Path 'C:\copilot' -ItemType Directory
Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile 'C:\copilot\copilot.exe' https://github.com/aws/copilot-cli/releases/latest/download/copilot-windows.exe
```

Comment: hit everything i needed and more. thanks!

Comment: you're welcome @Shea, glad this was helpful